# How to disable js script on specific page?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

Idea: I want to disable js script on specific page(e.g `new_post_path`), that is placed in `application.js`. On another page script should works. Have you any idea how to solve this problem? I thought to use loop `unless current_page?(new_post_path)`, but it's not work in js file.

Simple script to disable:

```
  window.setTimeout(function() {
      $(".alert").fadeTo(500, 0).slideUp(500, function() {
          $(this).remove();
      });
  }, 10000);
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set two attributes in the layout:

```
<body data-controller="<%= controller_name %>" data-action="<%= action_name %>">

</body>
```

and from your js, check the value of `data-controller` and `data-action` to know whether or not you want to run the script on that action.